# colorear texto en div editable innerHTML

Tags: javascript, color, innerhtml

Tengo un editor HTML de elaboración propia con unos selectores para minimas modificaciones del texto HTML para cambiar colores o tipo de fuente o insertar imagenes, etc.. y va funcionando perfectamente.
El editor cuenta con dos div editables, uno en el que se muestra la página web con sus imagenes y colores, y otro div editable con el innerHTML que si no se procesa, se ve todo en texto plano con letras todas de color negro.

En este último coloreo los tags para que se vean mejor por ejemplo <br> lo marco en azul, <p> lo marco en rojo, etc. y hasta ahora lo hago con execCommand de JavaScript, con el codigo:

```
document.designMode = "on";
var text1 = "<br>";
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.collapse(document.getElementById('divInnerHTML'), 0);
while (window. Find(text1)) {
document.execCommand("foreColor", false, "blue");
sel.collapseToEnd();
}
document.designMode = "off";
```

Ya digo que funciona bien pero ahora me encuentro con que execCommand ha quedado obsoleto por lo que tengo que buscar otra alternativa y no encuentro el codigo necesario para que los <br> se vean azules o los <p y los </p> se vean rojos o las subcadenas <img se vean verdes, etc.
Me imagino que una alternativa puede ser crear un array con todas las posiciones de las substring que contengan esas cadenas y luego marcar todas esas posiciones con el color que corresponda, es decir el foreColor del antiguo execCommand.

Voy a ir intentando distintas alternativas pero agradeceré a quien me pueda orientar sobre la manera de colorear código sin necesidad de execCommand.

Saludos al grupo.